# have someone succeed to do ssh connection using using paramiko module and dropbear in python2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko, dropbear

Has someone succeed to do ssh connection using paramiko module and dropbear in python2.7? I get  "Authentication failed" error when executing the code below

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("IP", username = "root")
```

The error which I get is.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Qb/QbUnittest/QbUnittest.py", line 624, in __call__
testMethod()
File "testDropBear_send_file.py", line 34, in runMe
    ssh.connect(self.terminal.xmlTerminalCfg.getIp(), username = USER_NAME)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 367, in connect
    look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 584, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

P.S
There is no need password for username "root". Dropbear version is 2016.73. paramiki 1.16. python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

For empty passwords (needless to say this is not recommended in terms of security) you have to explicitly set `password=""` in the `run()` call:

```
ssh.connect("IP",
            username = "root",
            password="",
            look_for_keys=False,
            allow_agent=False)
```

Comment: thanks for the responce.
I have tried in that way the result is the same

Comment: is a ssh session with a client such as openssh working, right? I tried that code with dropbear 2014.x and 2015.67 (paramiko 1.17) w/o issues.